# I am getting error around <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> line

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to java and learning spring-mvc framework. I'm Writing simple program to for login page . I'm getting error around

line.

Comment: I'm getting error around <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
line

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.